# How to serialize/deserialize using illinois-edison

Tags: java, nlp

I am using Edison ( http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/Edison ). 
I extract features using the curator, and save in the TextAnnotation file. 
How can I serialize/deserialize the file? When I directly try to serialize it, it gives an error:

```
static List<RelInstance> allInstance = ... 
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(".../dataless_rel_srl/dataless-rel/Data/SemEval-2010"));
oos.writeObject(allInstances);
oos.close();
```

The error is :

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.edison.sentences.SymbolTable
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1180)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:710)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:975)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
    at edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.relationsDataless.SemEval2010Reader.saveAllOnDisk(SemEval2010Reader.java:203)
    at edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.relationsDataless.SemEval2010Reader.main(SemEval2010Reader.java:52)
```

Comment: Its either RelInstance or it can't serialise an interface (List) try to serialise one, or an array.

Comment: No, it is the class : edu.illinois.cs.cogcomp.edison.sentences.SymbolTable inside Edison

Comment: That's just where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Have you tried using EdisonSerializationHelper? See here: http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/software/edison/apidocs/edu/illinois/cs/cogcomp/edison/sentences/EdisonSerializationHelper.html

Comment: @IllinoisNLP Yeah, that is what I figure it out later.  If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [EdisonSerializationHelper](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/software/edison/apidocs/edu/illinois/cs/cogcomp/edison/sentences/EdisonSerializationHelper.html). This class is created exactly for what you want to do.